# I can not throw my application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6.4

To my misfortune, update my iPhone 6 to version 9.0.1 (13A404) and I could not throw my application from Xcode. XCODE upgrade to the latest version (6.4) is impossible. Any solution to this that someone knows?

Comment: what do you mean by throw my app from xcode? Do you mean launch ?

Comment: Do you even lift bro?

Comment: I apologize for my English, I meant to run my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Xcode 7 to support iOS 9.0.1.

Comment: The last update that appeared to me in the store was 6.4, I found to download the 7. Thanks and sorry if I do not interpret well.